# element overwriting while using list.add(0,arrayObj) to add last item at top in arraylist android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am showing some server data using recyclerview which will show updated data to the top,and to update list i am calling a method after 15 sec each, first time i req server its working fine but after that when i am updating list with server data 15 sec each and trying to add the new item to top and show, its not working well ,more specific the problem is while the last item is pic and updated data is text its merged in output.

[image]

[image]

see the pics. last item was webadeal pic and when i updated list with data **"test"** its merged in UI.

here is my code:

fragment:

```
oncreateview(){
     //adapter initialization
        linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context_newsfeed);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            newsFeedAdapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(newsFeedClassArrayList, context_newsfeed);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(newsFeedAdapter);
            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context_newsfeed, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            if (WebViewActivity.getScrollPosition() != null) {
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Integer.valueOf(WebViewActivity.getScrollPosition()));
            }
            }
//below are two method. first is called for once which working well but second is for 15 sec each.

void updateNewsFeed(){

//        newsFeedClassArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        postId_ArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

//   allArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            newsFeedQuery= URLEncoder.encode("userId","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(ServiceClass.getDefaults("USERID",context_newsfeed),"UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("updatePostId","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(lastPostId,"UTF-8");

            if(asyncTaskClass==null || asyncTaskClass.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {

                asyncTaskClass = new AsyncTaskClass(context_newsfeed, new AsyncTaskResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void AsyncTaskResult(String result) throws JSONException {

                        Log.v("ResDUpdate", result);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        if (jsonArray.length() > 0){
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject tmpjsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.optString(i));
                            newsFeedClass_updated = new NewsFeedClass();

                            if (tmpjsonObject.getString("funpage").equals("1")) {

                                newsFeedClass_updated.setUserId_friends(tmpjsonObject.getString("user_id"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setPostId(tmpjsonObject.getString("id"));

                            /*if(postId==(null) || postId.equals("")|| Integer.valueOf(postId)<Integer.valueOf(tmpjsonObject.getString("id")))
                            {
                                ServiceClass.setDefaults("postId",tmpjsonObject.getString("id"),context_newsfeed);
                            }*/
                                // make post id arrayList
                                ContactListClass contactListClass_postId = new ContactListClass();
                                contactListClass_postId.setContactName(tmpjsonObject.getString("id"));   //post id
                                contactListClass_postId.setContactNumber(String.valueOf(i));  //index no
                                postId_ArrayList.add(contactListClass_postId);

                                //updated post id
                                if (Integer.valueOf(tmpjsonObject.getString("id")) > Integer.valueOf(lastPostId)) {
                                    lastPostId = tmpjsonObject.getString("id");
                                }

                                newsFeedClass_updated.setUserPicUrl_newsFeed(tmpjsonObject.getString("profile_pic"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setUserProName(tmpjsonObject.getString("author_name"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setStatus(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_content"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setLikeCount(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_likes"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setWowCount(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_wows"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setBlehCount(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_blehs"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setDislikeCount(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_dislikes"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setTimeStamp(tmpjsonObject.getString("post_time"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setVideo("");
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setYoutubeVideo("");
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setIsSharedValue(tmpjsonObject.getString("is_shared"));
                                newsFeedClass_updated.setIsFriend(tmpjsonObject.getString("is_by_friend"));



                                //post attachment // here image if more than one
                                imageList_FunPost = new ArrayList<>();
                                if (tmpjsonObject.getJSONArray("attachments").length() > 0) {

                                    JSONArray jsonArray_attachment = tmpjsonObject.getJSONArray("attachments");
                                    for (int i_attachment = 0; i_attachment < jsonArray_attachment.length(); i_attachment++) {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject_attachment = new JSONObject(jsonArray_attachment.optString(i_attachment));
                                        ContactListClass contactListClass = new ContactListClass();
                                        contactListClass.setContactName(InfoSetClass.getBaseUrl() + jsonObject_attachment.getString("file_path"));// post picture url save
                                        contactListClass.setContactNumber((tmpjsonObject.getString("id")));
                                        imageList_FunPost.add(contactListClass);
                                    }
                                    newsFeedClass_updated.setImageList(imageList_FunPost);
                                }
                                Log.v("ResDfsd","tes "+ newsFeedClassArrayList);
                                newsFeedClassArrayList.add(0,newsFeedClass_updated);// but as i need to show last item at top thats why i do this and prb raise.
                                Log.e("newsFeedClassArrayList","after adding new data from api response "+ newsFeedClassArrayList);

                            }
                        }
                            //that is fine, may be problem is else where
//                        allArrayList.addAll(newsFeedClassArrayList);
//                            newsFeedAdapter.swapList(newsFeedClassArrayList);
 //                       newsFeedAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                         newsFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //set list to service class
                        ServiceClass.setPostId_list(postId_ArrayList);
                    }
                        Log.v("ResDfsd","tesdf "+ newsFeedClassArrayList);
                    }
                });
                asyncTaskClass.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "POST", "mobileApi/getUpdatePost", newsFeedQuery);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        currentPageNo=holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem();
//        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        newsFeedClass=newsFeedClassArrayList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(InfoSetClass.getBaseUrl()+newsFeedClass.getUserPicUrl_newsFeed()).centerCrop().transform(new CircleTransform()).resize(50,50).into(holder.userProPicImg);

        holder.userProNameTvId.setText(newsFeedClass.getUserProName());

        if(newsFeedClass.getLikeCount()!=null)
            totalLikeWow=Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getLikeCount())+Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getBlehCount()) +Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getDislikeCount())+Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getWowCount());
        holder.likeCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(totalLikeWow));

        if(newsFeedClass.getCommentCount()!=null)
        holder.commentCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getCommentCount()));

        if(newsFeedClass.getShareCount()!=null){
            holder.shareCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getShareCount()));
        }

        if(!((newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(".jpg"))||(newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(".png"))||
                (newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains("https"))||(newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains("http")))) {
            holder.statusTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsFeedClass.getStatus()));
//            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {

            holder.newsFeedImageView.loadData(newsFeedClass.getStatus(), "text/html", null);
            holder.newsFeedImageView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = holder.newsFeedImageView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
            webSettings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();
//          holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        //image slider
        if(newsFeedClass.getImageList()!=null){

            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(context,newsFeedClass.getImageList());
            holder.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

            if(viewPagerAdapter.getCount()>1){
                holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()>1){
                holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()==viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()<viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                        if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()<=viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                            holder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPageNo++,true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
//            holder.viewPagerArrowIndicator.bind(holder.viewPager);
//            holder.viewPagerArrowIndicator.setArrowIndicatorRes(R.drawable.arrow_left_black_24dp,R.drawable.arrow_right_black_24dp);
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }else {
//            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.timeStampTvId.setText(newsFeedClass.getTimeStamp());


    }
```

Comment: I think you need to do a little more work on your end before posting.  Did you step through the code with a debugger to find the exact line where the error is occurring?

Comment: i have tried a lot

Comment: @AAA that text is status test means "holder.statusTv" text..?

Comment: yes should have been in it but not doing well that

Comment: your code is not really clear or friendly, it does not show if you have 2 types of view, text or image, or if the same view can have text , image or both, anyways, what i see, and since recycleViewer reuses same views , i think you need to check if the view is image only, then set the text view to `""` because if it was populated with text from a previous item it will remain there even if it's an image item

Answer (score 0):

Recycle View will reuse the item so we should set the value in bindView all time, but some value you didn't set properly, so do like this,

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        currentPageNo=holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem();
//        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        newsFeedClass=newsFeedClassArrayList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(InfoSetClass.getBaseUrl()+newsFeedClass.getUserPicUrl_newsFeed()).centerCrop().transform(new CircleTransform()).resize(50,50).into(holder.userProPicImg);

        holder.userProNameTvId.setText(newsFeedClass.getUserProName());

        if(newsFeedClass.getLikeCount()!=null)
            totalLikeWow=Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getLikeCount())+Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getBlehCount()) +Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getDislikeCount())+Integer.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getWowCount());
        holder.likeCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(totalLikeWow));

        if(newsFeedClass.getCommentCount()!=null) {
            holder.commentCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getCommentCount()));
        } else {
            holder.commentCountTv.setText("");
        }

        if(newsFeedClass.getShareCount()!=null){
            holder.shareCountTv.setText(String.valueOf(newsFeedClass.getShareCount()));
        } else {
            holder.shareCountTv.setText("");
        }

        if(!((newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(".jpg"))||(newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(".png"))||
                (newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains("https"))||(newsFeedClass.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains("http")))) {
            holder.statusTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsFeedClass.getStatus()));
            holder.newsFeedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            holder.newsFeedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.statusTv.setText("");

            holder.newsFeedImageView.loadData(newsFeedClass.getStatus(), "text/html", null);
            holder.newsFeedImageView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = holder.newsFeedImageView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
            webSettings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();
//          holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        //image slider
        if(newsFeedClass.getImageList()!=null){
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(context,newsFeedClass.getImageList());
            holder.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

            if(viewPagerAdapter.getCount()>1){
                holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()>1){
                holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                holder.leftArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()==viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            holder.rightArrowViewPagerId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()<viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                        if(holder.viewPager.getCurrentItem()<=viewPagerAdapter.getCount()){
                            holder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPageNo++,true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
//            holder.viewPagerArrowIndicator.bind(holder.viewPager);
//            holder.viewPagerArrowIndicator.setArrowIndicatorRes(R.drawable.arrow_left_black_24dp,R.drawable.arrow_right_black_24dp);
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }else {
            holder.viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.timeStampTvId.setText(newsFeedClass.getTimeStamp());


    }
```

Comment: image slider and status text are prb with

Comment: I added statusTv also, have a look

Comment: still same prb.,.,.,.,

Comment: I added your complete bindView, You have the adapter as a global variable, you should use local and some view you did update every time, I did that have a look.

Comment: if adapter would have problem then how it showing correct for first method

Comment: You should understand if 1st time working after scrolling and after scrolling or updating if its showing old item is definitely an object reuse issue. thats what I am trying to explain you.

Comment: i really couldnot get the prb. its just showing wrong when i use newsFeedClassArrayList.add(0,newsFeedClass_updated); 
but if i added the usual way without postion then also its working fine